Multi-hop SSH tunnel
I have two VPS servers, S1 and S2, with the following network setup:

My local machine can only access S1.
S1 can only connect to S2.
Only S2 has direct internet access.

I'm using the NetMod SSH tunnel client to connect to S1. What I want to achieve is to route my internet traffic through S1 and then through S2.
Since I'm using already existing SSH tunnel clients for windows and android I can't use the suggested answers which require executing additional or special commands on my local machine, I can only change settings on S1 and S2.
SSH Ports:

S1 = 22
S2 = 1202

I've tried several solutions posted here, but none have worked for me so far. Any help or guidance would be really appreciated!

The multi-hop is done through the initial ssh command, or if using PuTTY, configuring the Proxy command to first load the SSH profile the multi-hop will connect through via plink (I have pre-configured multi-hop PuTTY profiles for Windows here). I can create an answer later, but don't have the time at the moment.

@JW0914 Is there anyway to only change Server configurations without using PuTTY or a special command on the local machine? I'm connecting via NetMod to S1 without any issues, what i need that instead of connecting to S1:22 i can connect to S1:1202 and it will reroute to S2:1202 allowing me to VPN connect to the S2 server.
The reason i need to use NetMod is that it allows VPN like connection instead of proxy which PuTTY offers, It redirects all of my local machine's traffic automatically
